# how to create a open website using alfresco with list of read only documents

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I would like to create read-only documentation repository where any user can view and download documents (PDF, DOCX, PPT) publicly. Is this possible in alfresco to make a alfresco site completely anonymous?

I want a particular site inside the alfresco should not ask/redirect to login page and display all contents which I mark it in such a way

Comment: So, every user can see and download all documents, but can't edit them or add any new ones? Are the users required to login at all?

Comment: I want a particular site inside the alfresco should not ask/redirect to login page and display all contents which I mark it in such a way

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's possible, but I don't think that is the cleanest & quickest way.

What I would do is the following:

1. Create a custom share page
2. Change the share & repo webscript of these elements to allow guest, so in case you don't want to create a security breach for your private site, I'd copy/change/extend the needed repo webscripts with a custom one and do some extra checks in it.
3. Allow guest login in the alfresco-global.properties
4. Give the guest user Site.Consumer permission within the site (you'll probably will need to do this via the JS-Console or Java code

example page template which will be visible to everyone:

```
<page>  
<template-instance>guest-site-dashboard</template-instance>
<authentication>none</authentication>
<title>Guest Site Dashboard</title>
<title-id>page.guest-site-dashboard.title</title-id>
</page>
```

Comment: I've got a feeling that Dave Drapper demo'd something much like this at an Alfresco Conference ~18 months back, showing off how easy things are with Aikau. Might even be able to just re-use most of that!

Comment: Yep, with Aikau it's very easy to create new custom pages, the only thing it doesnt has a template page xml. so you'll need to put <page>
 <authentication>none</authentication>

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the external authentication without customising anything in Alfresco. With the external authentication you can use an external web server to manage your authentication. This is an OOTB configuration that is also well documented.

I have never done what I am going to suggest and so I could be wrong.

If, for example, you have in front of Alfresco an Apache server, you can configure it to automatically add the http header to authenticate the user as "guest" when the url points to the the public site.

This means of course that you need to know the site that is open a priori because you need to write the configuration in Apache.

I think that you can have a problem only if the same user after accessing the public site, accesses a site that needs authentication. Because Alfresco recognises the user as "guest" it won't redirect the browser to the login page.

If this use case is possible, there could be some workarounds:

1. You can configure Apache to redirect the user to the login page when the server returns a 401.
2. You can define a custom error page for 401 that invites the user to login. The link will reset the cookies and redirect to the login page.

If this works, you can have the public site without customisations.